# passcode to show content

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a simple set-up so that when a certain code is entered into a form box, then a hidden element shows. If you could help me out, that'd be great. Thanks!

```
<form>
    Enter the passcode to see the content:
    <input id="pwd" type="text" name="pwd" />
</form>
<div id="content" style="display:none;">
    testing 123
</div>
<script>
    $function(){
        $(form).keyup(function() {
            $('input').trigger('change');
        });
        if ($('pwd').val() == supportingcauses){
            $('content').show('slow');
        }
    };
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaruesink/RTG4f/

Comment: This is not the best idea since anyone who looks at your html page in HTML format will be able to see your hidden content... so no real reason to guard it with a password...

Comment: It look that nayish is suggesting a server trip which you can do with AJAX.

Comment: it doesn't have to be secure. it's just a little gimmick i need on the site. thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your only problem in your code is that your codes missing a bit of chars. Here's how it should look:

```
...
if ($('#pwd').val() == "supportingcauses"){
    $('#content').show('slow');
}
...
```

I added the `#` to signify its an id and the parenthesis to signify `supportingcauses` is a string.

**EDIT**

The full correct code would be:

```
<form>
    Enter the passcode to see the content:
    <input id="pwd" type="text" name="pwd" />
</form>
<div id="content" style="display:none;">
    testing 123
</div>
<script>
    $("#pwd").keyup(function() {
        if ($('#pwd').val() == "supportingcauses"){
            $('#content').show('slow');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Or as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/MrjxY/3/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a secure method of password safety but here is how to do it,

http://jsfiddle.net/RTG4f/1/